# WPF: richtextbox tab issue

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I am really confused at what is going on here. I have a rtb, and I have allowTab set to true, so the user can indent.

The problem is, there seems to be no tab character infront of the text. For example, if I have text that looks like:

```
this is some text
    and some more text
    and one more line
```

I would imagine, if I looked at the text in code, that it would look like:

```
this is some text \r\n\tand some more text\r\n\tand one more line
```

but instead it just looks like:

```
this is some text \r\nand some more text\r\nand one more line (notice there are 
no tabs)
```

The tabs are very important to me, as I need to keep track of "hierarchy" of lines, I need to know how much space is before lines. (either spaces or tabs (\t)). Is there a way I can see the tab space as \t's when I look at the string in code?

Should I just catch the key down event, and replace the tab key event with spaces? thats how I did it in a winforms project, but i figure WPF will have some neat way to handle it :)

Thanks!

*Edit* when I hit the tab button, does it change the paragraph textindent? aka, there is no noticeable difference in the text itself?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you getting the text back but it should work, test:

```
string text = "this is some text \r\n\tand some more text\r\n\tand one more line";

richTextBox1.AppendText(text);

text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
//text will be the same: "this is some text \r\n\tand some more text\r\n\tand one more line\r\n"
```

Comment: Ok, then you have to check the `TextIndent` for each block example: `(richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock)).ContentStart.Paragraph.TextIndent`